# Mapping categorical data in K-nearest neighbour

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have a data set which contains categorical data, for example:

```
+-----+-----+------+
| age | sex | grade|
+-----+-----+------+
| 18  |  M  |  59  |
+-----+-----+------+
| 19  |  F  |  16  |
+-----+-----+------+
```

How can i map the `sex` column to numerical data? generally how can i do map categorical data to numerical data in KNN? Is this a good idea to do this mapping?

Answer (score 0):

You can map M to 0 and F to 1.  In general, if you have N categories, you can map each category to a number in the range 1,2,..,N.  If N=2, this is fine for a k-nearest neighbor classifier.

If N>2, this is not a good idea for a k-nearest neighbor classifier, as it makes some assumptions (e.g., that the first category is more similar to the second category than the third).  If you want to use a k-nearest neighbor classifier and you have no knowledge about the meanings of the categories, the best you can do is to use a one-hot encoding.  If you do have some knowledge about the meanings of the categories, the best you can do is to define a distance function or similarity function between categories, and use that directly (instead of mapping the categories to numbers).